# Is it possible to create a local data source (DSN) to my development MSSQL LocalDB instance?

Tags: windows, database, dsn

A project using a legacy code library works in terms of DSN name, user, password - not an approach I'm very familiar with as a developer used to DB connection strings.

For testing, I have a LocalDB instance auto-deployed via Visual Studio. I know its connection string, I'm wondering if/how I can create a DSN for local testing that mirrors/wraps (not sure which term is correct) this connection, in the DSN Windows dialog:

[image]

What *is* the relationship between DSN and conenction string - or are is there no relationship and they're entirely different ways of referring to the same DB?

Thanks.

Comment: (I did query whether this is a SO or DBA quest, but DSN seems more a sysadmin sort of thing to me?)

Comment: well, first off there are user and system scoped DSNs. you adminster them in  windows using control panel > datasources. you do need to have installed an ODBC driver for the target database technology in question, so install it, rebvoot, and see if you have the options to create a DSN using that driver.

Comment: just for a definition, a DSN is kinda like a system-centric connection string. ODBC allowed system administrators to deploy connection strings and rights therein, seperately from the deployment of the programs that used them. in all honesty, its an outdated model in many ways and really doesn't make sense in the modern paradigm, which is why its largely legacy (or oracle, so same-same). modern applications handle their own connections, using (preferably) native drivers to do so.

Comment: @FrankThomas agree with all that legacy code as I say :) I've used this about 10-15 years ago most recently and I'm not a DB/sys guy so this is very unfamiliar to me in 2020

Comment: also note, the connection strings in your (newly posted) image are stock for MS office. a dsn to an external database will have simillar parameters to a connection sting. see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html . jusdt provide 127.0.0.1 to connect to a local db server instance.